# Internship in the UK/US as an Italian

Tags: visas, usa, uk, working-visas, italian-citizens

I am an Italian citizen currently studying in Germany. I have an Italian passport and an Italian ID. I would like to do an internship in the UK or in the US in the next year. When applying, I have to answer the following questions:

1. Are you entitled to work in this country?
2. Do you now or in the future need the help of the employer to obtain work authorization?

Unfortunately, I don't really know how this works and what I have to choose here.

Comment: Why are you applying for something without first knowing how it works?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think that's a reasonable question and you're welcome to ask follow up questions.

Comment: @Traveller Because he wants the internship?

Comment: @lambshaanxy I wasn’t being facetious, it was a genuine question. Not knowing how it works might lead to errors in the visa application (notwithstanding asking questions on TSE) and/or immigration rule breaches during the internship.

Comment: @Traveller Usually the visa sponsor can help with the application.

Comment: I always thought the employer helps and takes care of everything concerning the visa, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: This site is for short term travel like vacations. We have a site called [expatriates.se] for living and working abroad.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need a visa to work in both the UK and the US, so the answers are simple: you are not entitled to work, and you do need the employer's help with the work visa.